# Is there a default response for Rspec controller tests when no action is passed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I came accross this controller spec which has no action passed. It's clear for me that it's not testing anything. But the expectation for a `response.status == 200` doesn't fail. So I'd like to understand how Rspec builds the controller tests and if there's a default `response.status == 200`.

```
describe 'SomeController', type: :controller do 
  let!(:user){ FactoryGirl.create :admin_user }
  before { sign_in user }

  describe 'GET#action' do 
    it 'response is success' do 
      expect(response.status).to eq 200
    end
 end
end 




 Finished in 0.93954 seconds (files took 1.63 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [RSpec controller spec documents point out](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs):

> A controller spec is an RSpec wrapper for a Rails functional test
>   ([`ActionController::TestCase::Behavior`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb)).

So, looking at the the in-code documentation for `ActionController::TestCase::Behavior`, under the [Special Instance Variables section](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb#L247), we can see that `ActionController::TestCase` will automatically provide [a `@response` instance variable](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb#L258) ([readable as just `response` in the test](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb#L320)), which is "an [`ActionDispatch::TestResponse`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/testing/test_response.rb) object, representing the response of the last HTTP response".  So, that would seem to explain why there is a `response` able to be accessed without needing an explicit request made in a controller spec, but why is it's status `200`?

Well, `ActionDispatch::TestResponse` inherits from [`ActionDispatch::Response`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-0-0/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/response.rb), which [when initialized provides `200` as the default status](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-0-0/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/response.rb#L161).  You can even test this out in your rails console:

```
> ActionDispatch::TestResponse.new
=> #<ActionDispatch::TestResponse:0x007fc449789b68
 @blank=false,
 @cache_control={},
 @charset=nil,
 @committed=false,
 @content_type=nil,
 @cv=
  #<MonitorMixin::ConditionVariable:0x007fc449789848
   @cond=#<Thread::ConditionVariable:0x007fc449789820>,
   @monitor=#<ActionDispatch::TestResponse:0x007fc449789b68 ...>>,
 @etag=nil,
 @header={"X-Frame-Options"=>"SAMEORIGIN", "X-XSS-Protection"=>"1; mode=block", "X-Content-Type-Options"=>"nosniff"},
 @mon_count=0,
 @mon_mutex=#<Thread::Mutex:0x007fc449789a50>,
 @mon_owner=nil,
 @sending=false,
 @sending_file=false,
 @sent=false,
 @status=200, # <<< Here's your default status.
 @stream=#<ActionDispatch::Response::Buffer:0x007fc449789938 @buf=[], @closed=false, @response=#<ActionDispatch::TestResponse:0x007fc449789b68 ...>>>
```

So, I hope this deep dive assisted in your understanding of the `response` object in RSpec controller specs, as it certainly did mine.

Comment: Great answer Paul. It's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks